# How to add column automatically in hibernate.hbm.xml and users.java

Tags: java, hibernate

i have java project i am creating with hibernate using NetBeans ide7.4 till now i have created
users.hbm.xml file and users.java file which based on table in database but now i have added some more column in users table so please tell me how can i update my users.hbm.xml and users.java corresponding my database table when i increase table in database or add some more column in table for doing it i have fallow number of tutorial but still now i am facing problem so please solve my problem

before my users table has only 1 column

```
id
```

and my users.java is

```
package clinic.entity;
// Generated 17 Jan, 2014 4:36:15 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.6.0




public class Users  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private int id;

public Users() {
}

public Users(int id) {
   this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

and my users.hbm.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
 <!-- Generated 17 Jan, 2014 4:36:16 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.6.0 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="clinic.entity.Users" table="users" catalog="clinic_mgmt">
    <id name="id" type="int">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

now i have added 2 more column in table then schema is this

```
id|name |email
```

so tell me how to update my both file automatically

Comment: And... what have you actually tried? Have you looked at Hibernate reverse engineering yet? http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html

Comment: i have done this but still my problem is not solved please provide me correct answer

Comment: That is impossible without information about what your usecase looks like, what specifically you have tried and why it isn't working for you. What errors do you run into? What keeps you from using Hibernate reveng for this? You keep talking about "my problem" without even actually describing that problem.

Comment: please check my above code i have given before update table code

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to do things in the opposite direction: update Java first, then generate the database schema with  (because the xml file can contain most of the schema).

Now that you've added these columns, you must add field in your java file for each new column, then map them in the xml file.

For instance, if you have a new column email VARCHAR(128), you would add a String field in then java class, then map in with a <property> element in your xml file:

users.java:

```
private String email;

...

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String newValue) {
    email = newValue;
}
```

users.hbm.xml:

```
<property column="EMAIL" length="128" name="email"/>
```

Comment: is it any way to update the both file   automatically

Comment: @user3205372: No. When you're doing thing the other way around, you can use the schema generator (org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport), even though it doesn't deal with schema upgrade; but if you^re starting with the schema, you're on your own...

Answer (score 0):

you can use javax.persistence package annotation for that :

```
    @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstname;

    public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
```

---

Comment: tell me how to use it and where to use